# How the structure of the code behind file working in the web form? - .NET

Tags: .net, webforms, rendering, code-behind

I'm learing .NET and I'm wondering about the structure of the code behind file in web forms.

The structure is always:

```
using System;
namespace TestWebApp1
{
    public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Is it so that .NET always looks for the MyPage (filename) class en uses this to render the page?

Or can I have a file called Name1 and than use the class `Name2 : System.Web.UI.Page` for rendering the page? If yes, how do I get that working? Because I now get an exception?

Comment: It's a partial class - that is the page and the code-behind are the same class defined across 2 files and so use the same class name. The methods in the code behind are called at certain times during the page life cycle, the html is rendered at the appropriate step in the lifecycle. The classname in the `<%@ %>` at the top of the page should match the code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the top of your .aspx file :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="MyPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyPage" %>
```

The CodeFile attribute represents the physical file to use for code behind. 
The Inherits attribute represents the partial class that will be inherited for code behind.

So if you rename your partial class inside the code behind, you have to rename it in the inherits attribute as well.

Comment: Ah, I missed that bit. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

`ASP.NET` is a technology to create web-sites from two parts: the `HTML` to describe what the page looks like and the `code-behind`, determining how your controls respond to user input.
When creating new webforms, `ASP.NET` provides you with a template to work on and it initializes all your code-behind so you can start working on it.
So you should not change the name of the provided class manually, but rather chose a good name in the beginning. Otherwise you are confusing `ASP.NET` and it won't be able to merge these two parts to a web-page.
[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303247) is an article on `ASP.NET` introducing the model and how it works.

Comment: Yes, it is correct, what mathieu said! I was talking about that `ASP.NET` provides you everything to go with, so there is no need for such changes and what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know that .NET does a lot to make my life easier. But I always want to know a bit more about the inner workings of something to complete my understanding :)

Comment: You are welcome. This is why I provided you with a bit of insight and the link to the `KB`-article.